# Declare custom rule type as Vulnerability in SonarQube 6.3

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

I am using sonarQube 6.3 and when adding new custom rules for Php or Javascript, they are by default declared as Code smell. I would like to declare them as Vulnerability or bug.

Here is an example of a rule declaration

`@Rule(key = "Rule1",
priority = Priority.MAJOR,
name = "Rule 1 sould be used.",
tags = {"suspicious" })`

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to set the rule type using some special tags.

- Tag "bug" means type "bug"
- Tag "security" means type "vulnerability"

So try for example:

```
tags = {"suspicious", "bug"}
```

NB: This is documented in [API Javadoc](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinition.NewRule.html#setType-org.sonar.api.rules.RuleType-) (but hard to find I admit)